# Stack trace java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, dialog, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Sherlock Fragment, and i'm geting crash if  dialog opens when the app in minimise again open app.

Below is my exception:

```
Stack trace java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:200)
android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:166)
****.BookingDialogFragment$4$1.run(BookingDialogFragment.java:325)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

I'm using ft.commitAllowingStateLoss(); to comit fragment.

Here is my booking dialog code

```
mBookingDialogFragment.dismiss();
CabBookingFlow cabBookingFlow = new CabBookingFlow();
cabBookingFlow.setCancelable(false);
cabBookingFlow.show();
```

Comment: we might need `BookingDialogFragment` code and show us line 325 and how you invoke and dismiss it.

Comment: @zozelfelfo I have updated booking dialog code.help me to solve this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Friends Thanks for your comments and answers. i fixed this.

to change `mBookingDialogFragment.dismiss();` to `mBookingDialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();`

Answer (score 0):

Revert your sequence. First show the dialog and then dismiss the fragment.